# Changing statement separator in Intellij Idea or Datagrip like in Squirrel

Tags: intellij-idea, squirrel-sql, datagrip, database-tools

is it possible to change statement separator in Intellij Idea database tool?

To be exact, in squirrel, you can change statement separator, so you don't need to use symbol `;` but you can change it to different symbols like `@!?` etc.

Example

```
select * from users;
```

I would need

```
select * from users@
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is currently not possible, please follow/vote for this request [DBE-2968](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-2968)